# What keyboard layout does my MacBook 7.1 have?

Tags: keyboard-layout, macbook

I have a weird keyboard I guess

[image: My keyboard]

What layout is it? I can't find it in Ubuntu's keyboard layout setings.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

**I've found the image, which looks similar to your Macbook Keyboard Laytout. It looks like English(UK, Macintosh Internation) Layout**

You can even change it in Ubuntu.

- Open `Keyboard Layout` from `System Settings` (or search in dash)
- Go to <kbd>Layout</kbd>tab
- Click <kbd>+</kbd> in down-left
- Search for`English UK Macintosh`, you will get the list.
- You can press <kbd>Preview</kbd> button to see it. I'm attaching the images, it actually shows all the possible keys you can use for this Layout:

Keyboard Layout - **English (UK Macintosh International)**:

[image]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1384018_463084520478109_271805099_n.jpg))</sub>

<sub>Hope it would match with your MacBook Keyboard Layout. I'm sure after setting it you'll get the keys what shown in your Keyboard.</sub>

Comment: Nope, that's not the right layout. Look at the key at the left side of the 1... Thanks for attempting to help however :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply and pointing me to find the another keyboard layout. Check my answer, hope it matches with the right one!

Comment: Nope, it isn't that one too. Look at the 3 key: your screenshot shows a pound sign, while my keyboard has a # sign there. I have a weird keyboard I guess :(

Comment: I've told you that the layout it shows is the maximum possibility it would type. I think it would be then English(US Macintosh International) layout, Since it was not available at the `Keyboard Layout` options, I'm not confirmed. I just want you to set this layout and start typing all the keys in a text pad. If the keys what you typed matches with what in your keyboard, then it will be confirmed. **It is you only who can find out the layout** :) I was just telling you the way..

Comment: Do you know what are the 4 corners of each key stands for? When I press "Help" it just show a "page not found" error page. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomofumi I'm not sure about that.. :)